# How to handle if Microphone disconnects while using SpeechRecognition?

Tags: python, multithreading, error-handling, speech-recognition, pyaudio

So I'm using Speech recognition, with the listen_in_background function, which creates a thread. How can I catch the errors provided by this thread? If I put the caller function in Try... Statement, nothing happens. New to threading, so any helps?

Tried to put the the calling of the thread in Try... But doesn't help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text. The code should be a [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.